# C# read double numbers from .txt file

Tags: c#, file

How I can read all double numbers and save it in array from txt file?
I don't know the numbers elements.
In file can be also letters and other sign.
Numbers in .txt file:

```
2.3 g -0.2 s 1.2 5.8

2.0 .

-1.8 -7.6 1 46.1
```

I tried this:

```
List<double>numbers = new List<double>();
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("C:\\...\\Desktop\\file.txt"))
{
   BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);

   double doubleVal = reader.ReadSingle();
   numbers.Add(doubleVal);
}
```

Comment: Single is not a double. Single is float.

Comment: Numbers in a text file are just strings. Read the file with the normal IO methods to read text files. Split your lines at the blank between numbers and then try to parse each element resulting from the splitting

Comment: try to read line by line, and then parse each line use split

Comment: Ok, I read file by string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\user\\..\\textfile.txt"); but how i can split?

Comment: Are you *guaranteed* that the file contains nothing but doubles and whitespace? Or might there be some other stuff in there that you have to detect and ignore?

Comment: You ask how to read a text file and you're using a binary file reader. Use a text file reader.

Comment: No, I don't have guaranteed that fila contains only doubles and whitespace. Can be also letter.

Comment: @USER then why didn't you ask a more complete question. That changes everything

Comment: sorry, I edit equestion

Comment: A lot of it depends on how you'd want to handle ambiguous things, like "123,456,789".  Is that three separate numbers separated by commas, a 9-digit number, or no number at all?  Likewise, what about "6x8"  Is that two numbers, or no number?  My take is: generally, if you know that all valid possibilities have to have whitespace-ish characters around them, you should go with Eser+Eric 's solution.  If you expect you might have stuff like "'s around values, or non-standard separators like the pipe char, then you should go with a Regex solution.

Answer (score 1):

a little bit linq is enough

```
var numbers = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\temp\a.txt")
            .Split()
            .Where(n => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n))
            .Select(n => double.Parse(n, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            .ToList();
```

**EDIT**
OP's comment after half an hour : *No, I don't have guaranteed that fila contains only doubles and whitespace. Can be also letter.*

This of course invalidates some assumtions..... 
A new *Where* clause in this case would be `.Where(n => double.TryParse(n, out double x))` which is introduced in c#7

**EDIT 2**

Finally, after all those comments, using c#7 :

```
var numbers = File.ReadLines(@"d:\temp\a.txt")
        .SelectMany(line => line.Split()
                            .Select(s => (double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double d), d)))
        .Where(n => n.Item1)
        .Select(n => n.Item2)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: You could do `ReadAllLines` and skip the `.Split()`

Comment: @Bauss No a single line may contain multiple doubles as in the question

Comment: Ahh _Linq Wonders_, but still weak for me. Again, what happen if you meet a situation when something cannot be parsed as a double number? All in all I still prefer a standard solution when dealing with something like reading input data from a file, I am feeling more in control.

Comment: @Steve It all depends on the input.

Comment: @Steve: this is a perfectly reasonable standard solution to the problem that was asked. If the problem is "how do I parse a file that can contain doubles and other stuff", then this isn't a solution to that problem, but that wasn't the question that was asked.  If that *was* the question, then we could replace the select with a more sophisticated select.

Comment: Actually, you could just change the where clause, at the expense of parsing twice: `double d; input.Split().Where(x => Double.TryParse(x, out d)).Select(x => double.Parse(x, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))`

Comment: @EricLippert and Eser, well cannot disagree with that. All depends on input certainty.

Comment: @BurnsBA: You avoid the well-known problem with mutable variables in LINQ queries, but at a cost of parsing twice.  We can do better.

Comment: @BurnsBA: What you want is `public static double? AsDouble(this string s) => double.TryParse(s, out var d) ? (double?)d : (double?)null;` as an extension method, and then your query is `input.Split().Select(s => s.AsDouble()).Where(d => d.HasValue).Select(d => d.Value)`

Comment: @Eser: If the file is large then `ReadLines` can be more efficient than `ReadAllText` or `ReadAllLines`.  What you want to do there is `File.ReadLines(whatever).SelectMany(line => line.Split(whatever))...` and now you are back on track with a sequence of strings, but you haven't needed to read the entire file into memory at once.

Comment: @EricLippert Of course I know it, What I didn't know was this great attention to this simple question which hadn't any requirement. After OP's edit a Where(tryparse) is a better code

Comment: @EricLippert Eric thanks so much for posting on this site. I've learned so much from your comments / posts.

Answer (score 0):

Regex Powers Awaken!

```
string sampleString = "1.2 3 2.4\r\n3 a 9.4 3";  // you'd ordinarily get this from the file.
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"-?[0-9](?:\.[0-9]+)?|NaN|-Infinity|Infinity");
MatchCollection matches = myRegex.Matches(sampleString);
double[] nums = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => double.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();
```

Joking aside, basically, you can use regex to find all the matches for any sort of pattern.  The one in the code above simply looks for:

- One or more numbers, followed by a period, followed by one or more
  numbers

... or ...

- One or more numbers

It then uses some LINQ dark magic to convert the MatchCollection into a double[].

EDIT: Modified the regex to handle doubles the original didn't (including, embarassingly, negative numbers.)

Comment: Nice approach. You could also change your regex to allow for numbers with comma seperators as well ie 1,000,000

Comment: Other valid doubles: `"NaN Infinity -123.8e-123"`

Comment: @BurnsBA strange, "Infinity" doesn't parse for me.

Comment: I think it's because there's positive infinity and negative infinity.  I'm doubting the OP would *want* to add those doubles to the array, but if they did, it's a pretty easy fix: just add |NaN|-Infinity|Infinity to the regex to allow those specific values.  EDIT: Nm about the positive/negative.  Positive Infinity is just "Infinity" - which double.Parse can handle.  No idea what's going on for your comment, Rufus.